# Unclutter a bar plot with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have the given bar plot with three hirachies (color + inner-group + outer-group):

[image: Original image]

The figure look overloaded but I don't know how to split the x axis labels in a better way. A possible solution could be this sketch:

[image: Possible modification]

Since I did not figure out a good workflow for me yet, the minimal example is still somewhat cluttered. I used matlab2tikz as a start and did some tikzmodifications by hand afterwards:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Import der Plots aus Matlab
\usepackage{tikz} % Import der Plots aus Matlab
\newlength{\fheight}
\newlength{\fwidth}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\begin{document}
\setlength\fheight{0.2\columnwidth}
\setlength\fwidth{0.42\columnwidth}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.00000,0.56250}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.00000,0.18750,1.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.00000,0.87500,1.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.56250,1.00000,0.43750}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{1.00000,0.81250,0.00000}%
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
  \newlength{\myBarWidth}
  \setlength{\myBarWidth}{0.011\fwidth}
  \newlength{\myBarShift}
  \setlength{\myBarShift}{0.011\fwidth}
  \begin{axis}[%
  legend columns=4,
    width=\fwidth,
    height=\fheight,
    area legend,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0.25,
    xmax=11.75,
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
    xticklabels={
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          10\\
          \phantom{...}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          20\\
          \text{proposed},\pi_{\text{Th}\phantom{...}}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          30\\
          \phantom{...}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {},
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          10\\
          \phantom{...}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          20\\
          \text{proposed},\kappa_{\text{Th}}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          30\\
          \phantom{...}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {},
      {$\begin{array}{c}10\\\phantom{...}\end{array}$},
      {$\begin{array}{c}20\\\text{DOA-based}\end{array}$},
      {$\begin{array}{c}30\\\phantom{...}\end{array}$}
    },
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    ytick={0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100},
    ylabel={$\text{Accuracy}$},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.35)},anchor=north,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=5pt},
    /tikz/column 4/.style={column sep=5pt},
    /tikz/column 6/.style={column sep=5pt}
  }
    ]
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-3\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor1
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  100\\  2  100\\  3  100\\  4  0\\
      5  100\\  6  100\\  7  100\\  8  0\\
      9  100\\ 10  100\\ 11  100\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 0$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-2\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor2
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1 99.8\\  2  100\\  3  100\\  4  0\\
      5  100\\  6  100\\  7  100\\  8  0\\
      9 32.8\\ 10  100\\ 11  100\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 1$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-1\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor3
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  98.4\\  2  99.4\\  3  90.6\\  4  0\\
      5  98.2\\  6  97.4\\  7  90.4\\  8  0\\
      9  14.4\\ 10    79\\ 11  98.8\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 2$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=0\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor4
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  87.4\\  2  99.4\\  3  95.8\\  4  0\\
      5  92.8\\  6  98.4\\  7  91.6\\  8  0\\
      9     1\\ 10  27.2\\ 11  79.6\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 3$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=1\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor5
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  63.8\\  2  98.2\\  3  93.6\\  4  0\\
      5    80\\  6  94.4\\  7  85.4\\  8  0\\
      9     0\\ 10  34.4\\ 11  60.6\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 4$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=2\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=red!75!orange
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  31.8\\  2    94\\  3    92\\  4  0\\
      5  56.6\\  6  81.8\\  7    83\\  8  0\\
      9   0.2\\ 10  40.6\\ 11  52.2\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 5$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=3\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=black!50!red
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1     7\\  2  57.2\\  3  56.6\\  4  0\\
      5  31.6\\  6    39\\  7  32.4\\  8  0\\
      9     0\\ 10     0\\ 11     0\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 6$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/usMbLaYt)

Comment: The clutter is due to the legend. Make it smaller and to the right and it would be OK.

Comment: That is indeed a good advice. How can I split up the xlabel such that I can add the labels on top of the figure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modifications:

1. Added `font=\scriptsize` in legend style.
2. Moved legend to the top by `at={(rel axis cs: 0.5,1.05)}`
3. Changed `width` to `width=1.5\fwidth,`
4. Removed all `\phantom{...}`
5. Added `\\[-2.5ex]
         \underbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-0.5ex]`

With these, we get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Import der Plots aus Matlab
%% \usepackage{tikz} % not needed pgfplots loads this too
\newlength{\fheight}
\newlength{\fwidth}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\begin{document}
\setlength\fheight{0.2\columnwidth}
\setlength\fwidth{0.42\columnwidth}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.00000,0.56250}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.00000,0.18750,1.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.00000,0.87500,1.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.56250,1.00000,0.43750}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{1.00000,0.81250,0.00000}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
  \newlength{\myBarWidth}
  \setlength{\myBarWidth}{0.011\fwidth}
  \newlength{\myBarShift}
  \setlength{\myBarShift}{0.011\fwidth}
  \begin{axis}[%
  legend columns=4,
    width=1.5\fwidth,
    height=\fheight,
    area legend,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0.25,
    xmax=11.75,
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
    xticklabels={
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          10
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          20\\[-2.5ex]
          \underbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-0.5ex]
          \text{proposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          30
        \end{array}$
      },
      {},
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          10
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          20\\[-2.5ex]
          \underbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-0.5ex]
          \text{proposed},\kappa_{\text{Th}}
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          30
        \end{array}$
      },
      {},
      {$\begin{array}{c}10\end{array}$},
      {$\begin{array}{c}20\\[-2.5ex]
          \underbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-0.5ex]\text{DOA-based}\end{array}$},
      {$\begin{array}{c}30\end{array}$}
    },
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    ytick={0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100},
    ylabel={$\text{Accuracy}$},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
legend style={at={(rel axis cs: 0.5,1.05)},anchor=south,draw=black,font=\scriptsize,fill=white,legend cell align=left,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=5pt},
    /tikz/column 4/.style={column sep=5pt},
    /tikz/column 6/.style={column sep=5pt}
  }
    ]
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-3\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor1
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  100\\  2  100\\  3  100\\  4  0\\
      5  100\\  6  100\\  7  100\\  8  0\\
      9  100\\ 10  100\\ 11  100\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 0$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-2\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor2
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1 99.8\\  2  100\\  3  100\\  4  0\\
      5  100\\  6  100\\  7  100\\  8  0\\
      9 32.8\\ 10  100\\ 11  100\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 1$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-1\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor3
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  98.4\\  2  99.4\\  3  90.6\\  4  0\\
      5  98.2\\  6  97.4\\  7  90.4\\  8  0\\
      9  14.4\\ 10    79\\ 11  98.8\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 2$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=0\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor4
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  87.4\\  2  99.4\\  3  95.8\\  4  0\\
      5  92.8\\  6  98.4\\  7  91.6\\  8  0\\
      9     1\\ 10  27.2\\ 11  79.6\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 3$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=1\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor5
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  63.8\\  2  98.2\\  3  93.6\\  4  0\\
      5    80\\  6  94.4\\  7  85.4\\  8  0\\
      9     0\\ 10  34.4\\ 11  60.6\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 4$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=2\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=red!75!orange
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  31.8\\  2    94\\  3    92\\  4  0\\
      5  56.6\\  6  81.8\\  7    83\\  8  0\\
      9   0.2\\ 10  40.6\\ 11  52.2\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 5$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=3\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=black!50!red
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1     7\\  2  57.2\\  3  56.6\\  4  0\\
      5  31.6\\  6    39\\  7  32.4\\  8  0\\
      9     0\\ 10     0\\ 11     0\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 6$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Here is another layout:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Import der Plots aus Matlab
%% \usepackage{tikz} % not needed pgfplots loads this too
\newlength{\fheight}
\newlength{\fwidth}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\begin{document}
\setlength\fheight{0.2\columnwidth}
\setlength\fwidth{0.42\columnwidth}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.00000,0.56250}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.00000,0.18750,1.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.00000,0.87500,1.00000}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.56250,1.00000,0.43750}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{1.00000,0.81250,0.00000}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, trim axis left, trim axis right]
  \newlength{\myBarWidth}
  \setlength{\myBarWidth}{0.011\fwidth}
  \newlength{\myBarShift}
  \setlength{\myBarShift}{0.011\fwidth}
  \begin{axis}[%
  legend columns=4,
    width=1.5\fwidth,
    height=\fheight,
    area legend,
    scale only axis,
    clip=false,
    xmin=0.25,
    xmax=11.75,
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
    xticklabels={
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          10
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          20
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          30
        \end{array}$
      },
      {},
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          10
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          20
        \end{array}$
      },
      {$\begin{array}{c}
          30
        \end{array}$
      },
      {},
      {$\begin{array}{c}10\end{array}$},
      {$\begin{array}{c}20\end{array}$},
      {$\begin{array}{c}30\end{array}$}
    },
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    ytick={0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100},
    ylabel={$\text{Accuracy}$},
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
legend style={at={(rel axis cs: 0.5,-0.3)},anchor=north,draw=black,font=\scriptsize,fill=white,legend cell align=left,
    /tikz/column 2/.style={column sep=5pt},
    /tikz/column 4/.style={column sep=5pt},
    /tikz/column 6/.style={column sep=5pt}
  }
    ]
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-3\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor1
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  100\\  2  100\\  3  100\\  4  0\\
      5  100\\  6  100\\  7  100\\  8  0\\
      9  100\\ 10  100\\ 11  100\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 0$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-2\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor2
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1 99.8\\  2  100\\  3  100\\  4  0\\
      5  100\\  6  100\\  7  100\\  8  0\\
      9 32.8\\ 10  100\\ 11  100\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 1$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=-1\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor3
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  98.4\\  2  99.4\\  3  90.6\\  4  0\\
      5  98.2\\  6  97.4\\  7  90.4\\  8  0\\
      9  14.4\\ 10    79\\ 11  98.8\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 2$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=0\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor4
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  87.4\\  2  99.4\\  3  95.8\\  4  0\\
      5  92.8\\  6  98.4\\  7  91.6\\  8  0\\
      9     1\\ 10  27.2\\ 11  79.6\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 3$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=1\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=mycolor5
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  63.8\\  2  98.2\\  3  93.6\\  4  0\\
      5    80\\  6  94.4\\  7  85.4\\  8  0\\
      9     0\\ 10  34.4\\ 11  60.6\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 4$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=2\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=red!75!orange
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1  31.8\\  2    94\\  3    92\\  4  0\\
      5  56.6\\  6  81.8\\  7    83\\  8  0\\
      9   0.2\\ 10  40.6\\ 11  52.2\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 5$};
    \addplot[
    ybar,
    bar width=\myBarWidth,
    bar shift=3\myBarShift,
    draw=black,
    fill=black!50!red
    ]
    plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
      1     7\\  2  57.2\\  3  56.6\\  4  0\\
      5  31.6\\  6    39\\  7  32.4\\  8  0\\
      9     0\\ 10     0\\ 11     0\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$K = 6$};
  \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs: 2,105) {$\begin{array}{c}
          \text{proposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}\\[-0.7ex]
          \overbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-2.25ex]
        \end{array}$};
  \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs: 6,105) {
          $\begin{array}{c}
          \text{proposed},\kappa_{\text{Th}}\\[-0.7ex]
          \overbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\kappa_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-2.25ex]
        \end{array}$};
  \node[anchor=south] at (axis cs: 10,105) {
          $\begin{array}{c}
          \text{\text{DOA-based}}\\[-0.7ex]
          \overbrace{\hphantom{\text{roposed},\pi_{\text{Th}}}}\\[-2.25ex]
        \end{array}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. I appreciate two varying answers.